# Как передать словарь в аргумент argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

Как сделать так, чтобы `argparse` принимал произвольное количество (0+) опциональных аргументов вида "ключ-значение" в 1 переменную?

Пример:

```
my_prog.exe --filter_range 42 --filter_type str --filter_time 12:03
```

Для такого входа надо получить переменную-словарь `{'filter_range': '42', 'filter_type': 'str', 'filter_time': '12:03'}`.

Попутно вопросы: 1) можно ли задать диапазон для количества таких фильтров (фильтров может быть только от 0 до 5, например) или возможный список ключей (могут быть только фильтры `'filter_range'` и `'filter_type'`, например); 2) можно ли задать типы/диапазоны для ключа и значения (в примере первое значение может быть только натуральным числом).

Можно каждый аргумент задать отдельно, но тогда для составления словаря надо писать сложную логику: отличать такие фильтры от других аргументов, проверять их значения на `None` и т.п..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Вариант 1, словарь как единый аргумент

Передавать словарь можно например как цельную строку в формате JSON:

```py
import argparse
import json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-d', '--my-dict', type=json.loads)
```

Использовать так:

```py
args = parser.parse_args(['-d', '{\"key1\":\"value1\"}'])
print(args)
```

#### Вариант 2, словарь на ключевых словах

Если хочется использовать синтаксис ключевых слов, как для обычных аргументов, то `argparse` вам не поможет, т.к он создан для работы с конкретными, заранее определёнными ключевыми словами, и надо выбирать что-то из следующих вариантов:

- Если есть какая-то польза от `argparse`, то возможно имеет смысл его применять и расширять, например, используя метод `.parse_known_args()`.
- Можно посмотреть альтернативные библиотеки для обработки консольных аргументов, например [click](https://pypi.org/project/click/), [argh](https://pypi.org/project/argh/), что-то ещё. Возможно где-то в них уже реализован этот функционал.
- Если нигде нет, а очень хочется именно такой синтаксис, то ничто не мешает написать собственный парсер `:)`

Comment: О `parse_known_args` не знал, спасибо. Первый вариант, конечно, для пользователя не очень удобен

Answer (score 0):

Покурил маны и нашёл 3 варианта подходящих ([реализация первых двух](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38884513), [примеры для третьего](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11637293)):

1. Сделать 2 парсера. Первый обрабатывает всё кроме фильтров с помощью `parse_known_args()`, остальное обрабатывает второй.
2. В одном парсере добавить 2 группы (нефильтры и фильтры) с помощью `add_argument_group()`. Это было бы идеально, но проблема в том, что эти группы позволяют только красиво печатать хелп, а получить аргументы, относящиеся к определённой группе, можно только с помощью незадокументированного `_group_actions`.
3. Использовать `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` при добавлении аргументов. В таком случае аттрибут не будет добавляться в объект вообще, а не получать значение `None`. Тогда можно проитерироваться по всем необработанным аргументам класса парсера с помощью `vars()`, `dir()` и подобного без проверки значений.